# Validity of the UITableView Cells in ViewWill Appear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

**What I have**
1). Container has `UITableView`, which has two custom `UITableViewCells`.

2). Core Data has certain entity which has a text to be displayed at
    `UITableViewCell` each time I get into the `View`.

**What i am doing ?**

1) I have chosen `-viewWillAppear` method which gets invoked each time the view is visible.

2) In `-viewWillAppear`, I retrieved the data from core data.

3) Retrieved particular cell from `UITableView`

```
NSUInteger idxArr[] ={2,0};    // 2 nd section, 0th Row. 

NSIndexPath *cPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:idxArr length:2];

myCell *tCell = (myCell *)[self.settings cellForRowAtIndexPath:cPath];
tCell.myLabel.text = rec.servername;  // rec.servername is from DC.
```

When I checked in the lldb,

```
tCell was nil.
```

---

**Questions:**
1) It is the right way of getting the Cell ?

2) Or, By the time `-viewWillAppear`, does the UITableView not Ready ?

I am sure.

Comment: try to call `[self.settings reloadData]` first. seems like your tableview isn't ready

Answer (score 0):

You should populate the cells by conforming to tableView dataSource protocol and then in your viewWillAppear you should call reloadData on your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `reloadData` for tableview, We need to call `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` before getting cell from `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Because, As we are calling a row in section 2, it might not be in the visible area until we scroll. So, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

Method `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` shouldn't be called programically. It's a data source method for `UITableView` and it contain some cell reuse optimalizations. If you update the view after scrolling down and up `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called again and your changes won't be visible.

If you want to update specific cell you should update make changes in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    YourData *data = //Get your data here
    if (data.isReady) {
        cell.tf.text = data[indexPath.row].text; 
    } else {
        cell.tf.text = @"Not ready yet. Need to reload this cell later"; 
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And then call method below when you finish fetch your data.

```
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *) withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If you want to reload whole tableView (usually it's not slow) as @salaman140 says you can call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to update all visible cells.

If I were you I wouldn't use:

```
NSUInteger idxArr[] ={2,0};    // 2 nd section, 0th Row. 
NSIndexPath *cPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:idxArr length:2];
```

I would (is much more clear):

```
NSIndexPath *cPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];
```